# convert list output from tapplying quantile() into an array with quantile as a dimension

Tags: r

The below nonsense example is just for the sake of reproducibility. I have output  similar to below as a result of tapplying the quantile function over a data frame. However, this is not quite what I want. Rather than having a list of vectors, each containing  the 10% and 90% quantile, I want an array with all the dimensions of the list returned by the tapply, plus another quantile dimension (two levels, 10% and 90%). Is there any way to convert my tapply output into this?

```
 example.A <- chickwts; example.A$fac2 <- "A"
example.B <- chickwts; example.B$fac2 <- "B"
 example.1 <- rbind(example.A, example.B); example.1$fac3 = "a"
example.2 <- rbind(example.A, example.B); example.2$fac3 = "b"
 example <- rbind(example.1, example.2)
 names(example)[2] <- "rep"; levels(example$rep) <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")

example <- tapply(example$weight, list(example$rep, example$fac2, example$fac3), quantile, probs =c(0.1, 0.9))
```

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this what you are seeking? (It wasn't clear to me if you wanted an actual `array` object of if this was what you intended)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

example %>%
  group_by(rep, fac2, fac3) %>%
  summarise(q10 = quantile(weight, probs = 0.10),
            q90 = quantile(weight, probs = 0.90)) %>%
  gather(quantile, value, q10, q90)
```